# ajaxSubmit: Duplicate Entry on the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form and a input type file inside.

```
<form id='imageform' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='php/exec/add-message-image-exec.php' style='clear:both'>
    <div id='imageloadstatus' style='display:none'><img src='assets/loader.gif' alt='Uploading....'/></div>
    <div id='imageloadbutton'>
        <div class='file-field input-field'>
            <div class='btn'>
                <span>Upload</span>
                <input type='file' name='file' id='photoimg'/>
            </div>
            <div class='file-path-wrapper'>
                <input class='file-path validate' type='text'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

It performs whenever i attach an image in the input file, and an ajax will handle it to submit it automatically and save it to the database.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#photoimg').on('change', function () {
        var A = $('#imageloadstatus');
        var B = $('#imageloadbutton');

        $('#imageform').ajaxSubmit({target: '#preview',
            beforeSubmit: function () {
                A.show();
                B.hide();
            },
            success: function () {
                A.hide();
                B.show();
            },
            error: function () {
                A.hide();
                B.show();
            }}).submit();

    });
});
```

My problem is that it submits the image twice and save it to my database/table twice. But when i remove the `.submit();` inside my script, it only perform once but there's a small modal-like window and another screen appeared whenever i attach an image/submit.

Comment: what kind of window appears ? can you show the screenshot.

Comment: It may be that your ajax is submitting, and then the form is actually submitting as well. On the form, you could try removing the `action=` and adding `onsubmit="return false;"` just to check...

Comment: here is the sample image when i remove the .submit(); on the script and also on removing the action and adding a onsubmit='return false;' in the form. 
http://imgur.com/sn0DE39

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove 'action' and put it in an ajax POST request instead.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#photoimg').on('change', function () {
    var A = $('#imageloadstatus');
    var B = $('#imageloadbutton');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/exec/add-message-image-exec.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#imageform').serialize(),
        beforeSubmit: function () {
            A.show();
            B.hide();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //do something with data
            //ex: console.log()
            console.log(data);
            A.hide();
            B.show();
        },
        error: function () {
            A.hide();
            B.show();
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: it says that 
SyntaxError: missing } after property list
data: $('imageform').serialize();

Comment: when i remove the semicolon at the end of the serialize it has no error after refreshing the page but when i submit an image. it displays that $(...).ajax is not a function.

Comment: @Duplicated If this works please consider to hit checked button as an accepted answer. Best regards :)